# Why doesn't echo -e interpret a new line?

Tags: bash, newlines

In bash, when I write this line

```
new_line="new\nline"
```

I get this as expected:

```
echo $new_line
new\nline
```

And this also works as expected:

```
echo -e $new_line 
new
line
```

as it says in a manual: `-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`
However, this doesn't give me an interpreted `\n` new line character:

```
cur_log=$(who)
echo -e $cur_log
myuser pts/0 2017-01-19 07:10 (:0) myuser pts/1 2017-01-19 09:26 (:0) myuser pts/4 2017-01-19 09:14 (:0)
```

I thought that there is no new line character but if I write:

```
echo "$cur_log"
```

I get new line character interpreted.

```
myuser  pts/0        2017-01-19 07:10 (:0)
myuser  pts/1        2017-01-19 09:26 (:0)
myuser  pts/4        2017-01-19 09:14 (:0)
```

Why doesn't `echo -e $cur_log` interpret new line character but `echo -e $new_line does?

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/65304), in particular the section **Why do I need to write "$foo"? What happens without the quotes?**

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio Not a dupe. OP wants to NOT have newlines interpreted when using echo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is in your first variable (`new_line`), there is only an escape sequence (i.e. `\n` = `backslash` followed by `n`) which is passed unchanged to `echo`, while in the second one (`cur_log`), there are actual newlines which are stripped out by the shell being part of the `IFS` variable.

A new line is, under Unix/Linux, a single character which [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code is `10` (line-feed). When a file containing this character is displayed on screen, it is converted into two characters, carriage-return plus line feed (`CR-LF`), `10` + `13`. When an editor like `gedit` is opens such a file, it stores each line separately. Linefeed is only used to detect the separation between two contiguous lines. `\n` is made of two characters, ASCII `92` + `110`. If you edit a file containing occurrences of `\n` these two characters will be left unchanged and displayed as is, unlike real newlines.

Comment: I thougt that actual new lines are only lines with \n character

Comment: No, that's just a convention to represent new lines.

Comment: And if I write in vim text in two line how gedit will know that this file has two lines? Isn't hiden \n used there?